# How do I update a text label in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI text label and i want to write something in it after I press a button.

Here is my code:

```
Button(action: {
  registerRequest() // here is where the variable message changes its value
}) {
  Text("SignUp")
}

Text(message) // this is the label that I want to change
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Please don't add back the `xcode` tag as it's irrelevant to your question. That tag should only be used for question specifically concerning the Xcode IDE. Your question is purely about Swift and SwiftUI.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With only the code you shared it is hard to say exactly how you should do it but here are a couple good ways:

The first way is to put the string in a [`@State`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) variable so that it can be mutated and any change to it will cause an update to the view. Here is an example that you can test with Live Previews:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct UpdateTextView: View {
    @State var textToUpdate = "Update me!"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.textToUpdate = "I've been udpated!"
            }) {
                Text("SignUp")
            }
            Text(textToUpdate)
        }
    }
}

struct UpdateTextView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UpdateTextView()
    }
}
```

If your string is stored in a class that is external to the view you can use implement the [`ObservableObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject) protocol on your class and make the string variable [`@Published`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published) so that any change to it will cause an update to the view. In the view you need to make your class variable an [`@ObservedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/observedobject) to finish hooking it all up. Here is an example you can play with in Live Previews:

```swift
import SwiftUI

class ExternalModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var textToUpdate: String = "Update me!"
    func registerRequest() {
        // other functionality
        textToUpdate = "I've been updated!"
    }
}

struct UpdateTextViewExternal: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ExternalModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.viewModel.registerRequest()
            }) {
                Text("SignUp")
            }
            Text(self.viewModel.textToUpdate)
        }
    }
}

struct UpdateTextViewExternal_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UpdateTextViewExternal(viewModel: ExternalModel())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple @State example:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var name = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Please enter your NAME...").padding().bold()
        TextField("Enter your name", text: $name)
        Text(name.count % 2 == 0  ? "": "")
    }
    .padding()
}
```

}
[image: See Working example:]